# Computer program for factorization into irreducible polynomials over $\mathbb{Z}_{p^k}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, factoring, irreducible-polynomials, sagemath, magma-cas

Hensel's Lemma allows us to factor a polynomial uniquely into basic irreducible factors over $\mathbb{Z}_{p^k}$. Is there a SAGE or Magma command that gives this factorization?
Or can anyone help in writing a small script that handles this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this question, technically speaking, counts as a programming question?

Comment: Maybe a small script can handle this?.. Not a complicated program. Maybe.. Someone working on Z_p^k may have some information about this.

Comment: It might be worth looking into a CAS like Maxima or Maple.

Comment: You probably mean $\mathbb{Z}_{p^k}$ and not $\mathbb{Z}_p^k$ ?

Comment: Right, of course, I edited, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, you can do this with [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org), using `Factors`:

```
gap> f:= CyclotomicPolynomial( GF(2), 7 );
x_1^6+x_1^5+x_1^4+x_1^3+x_1^2+x_1+Z(2)^0
gap> Factors( f );
[ x_1^3+x_1+Z(2)^0, x_1^3+x_1^2+Z(2)^0 ]
gap> Factors( PolynomialRing( GF(8) ), f );
[ x_1+Z(2^3), x_1+Z(2^3)^2, x_1+Z(2^3)^3, x_1+Z(2^3)^4, 
  x_1+Z(2^3)^5, x_1+Z(2^3)^6 ]
```

(see GAP manual [here](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap66.html#X83511D517B544F36) for the documentation of `Factors`).

Comment: P.S. Of course, GAP is not the unique system capable of doing this, but one of the advantages of doing this in GAP is that it's open-source (as well as Sagemath and Maxima suggested in comments by others).

Comment: Thank you in advance. I have usen GAP several times when dealing with Group Theory, and I follow also the GAP forum, but I haven't thought that it might have been handy in factoring polynomials. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, glad to see you on this site too!